# Openshift - Warning: weekly cron run terminated as it exceeded max run time

Tags: cron, openshift

I have a script that updates few thousand records on openshift. After each request it sleeps 1 second. So I do not meet [5 minut][1]. I am using nohup with, but openshift kills that script anyway.
This is my nohup:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup /var/lib/openshift/526ed6ba4382eca7ff000024/python/virtenv/bin/python /var/lib/openshift/526ed6ba4382eca7ff000024/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/digrin/manage.py crontab run 2d73136da64a34e81327609dd1dfe69b & # update_historic_price_cron
```

log:

```
/var/lib/openshift/526ed6ba4382eca6ff000024/cron/bin/cron_runjobs.sh: line 111: 294808 Killed                  $executor "$SCRIPTS_DIR"
__________________________________________________________________________
Tue Apr  7 17:21:10 EDT 2015: END hourly cron run - status=137
__________________________________________________________________________

Warning: hourly cron run terminated as it exceeded max run time
________________________________________________________________
```

Openshift kills it after 20 minutes. Is there a way to run that cron longer? I only need to run it once a year, but I have put it in weekly dir.

Comment: Try runing the script with nohup &

Comment: I tried, still killed. It just means it will run in the background, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I do not know how to avoid 20 minutes run time limit. But I used a few workarounds. If you need, you can run it hourly and filter number of handled objects internally.

**Dividing db objects into parts**:

```
limit_per_query = int(Stock.objects.count() / 23)  + 10
hour = datetime.now().hour
for stock in Stock.objects.all().order_by("symbol")[hour*limit_per_query:hour*limit_per_query+limit_per_query]:
    stock.update() ...
```

If you need to run cron only once a month/year, you may add it to hourly/daily cron folder and then limit in method:

```
def update_spinoff_cron():
    if (datetime.now().day not in [1,2]):
        print("I am not updating spinoff today :) may be tomorrow.")
        return
    spinoff_update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping for 1 second in between each request is going to make your script run longer, not save you from the 5 minute time out.  You should remove that part of the script so that it runs more quickly.

Another suggestion is to run your updates in batches, maybe select a few hundred each time to update based on a timestamp of last updated or something.

Using & to put your script into the background should work.  Can you post the contents of your cron file that you are using?

Comment: I can't change sleep, because api provider would ban me. As well as batch requests. I have posted cron file, it runs django-cron and hash stands for task defined in settings.py file. I'll check background option one more time.

Comment: You can see my original cronfile in question(only few signs in UUID changed). Openshift kills it even if I use &.